# Questions on traffic flow within azure

Tags: azure

When there is communication between azure apps and other services like storage, service bus etc is there a way to make communication within azure (without going to the internet ). in the case of VMs it is achieved by private IP addresses within a Vnet .can this be achieved for other services ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no Virtual Network integration (i.e. talk over private IPs) for Azure Storage or Service Bus.

For each Azure service, if you read through the documentation pages, you should be able to tell whether it can be VNET integrated or not.

e.g. Azure Redis Cache can sit in a VNET:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-how-to-premium-vnet/

> The Azure Redis Cache premium tier includes clustering, persistence, and **virtual network (VNet) support**. A VNet is a private network in the cloud. When an Azure Redis Cache instance is configured with a VNet, it is not publicly addressable and can only be accessed from virtual machines and applications within the VNet.

Azure SQL can't. But - according to this answer here - it's coming:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/5537689-allow-sql-database-to-join-virtual-network-vpn

For all publicly exposed Azure services, security is achieved through the **secret** contained in the connection string and inbound public IP whitelisting (where applicable - e.g. Azure SQL's firewall).

Comment: so the services which do not have vnet integration always go via internet and one ends up paying some transaction charges for the egress data. I am aware of the security via SAS token etc, was just curious on what are the options to have the traffic flow within azure given that both the app and the services are hosted in azure only.

Comment: That's incorrect. Traffic that stays within the same Azure Region is free of charge, ingress or egress. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/data-transfers/ "_Is data transfer between Azure services located within the same region charged?
No. For example, an Azure SQL database in the same region will not have any additional data transfer costs._"

Comment: is within the same region mean originate in the region go to internet and then enter another resource in the same region ?? how do they keep track that if that is coming from same region once it is coming via internet?

Comment: It doesn't go out to the Internet. That traffic stays in the Azure datacenter. Think of it as going from Rack #22 to Rack #127.

Comment: @Aravind - evilSnobu is 100% correct. There are no egress charges for any service-to-service communication within a region, and never have been. There's only over-the-internet traffic when connecting to something outside of the region (such as another Azure region, your on-premises facility, etc.

Comment: My point is the if you use sdk or rest api you are hitting the Internet exposed endpoint. So it means the traffic comes from the Internet onto the endpoint.  Does azure check the source of the request to distinguish the calls?

Comment: Just because you're talking to Public IP Addresses doesn't mean you're talking over the Internet. You are talking over the Azure backbone network, which also exposes Public endpoints.